# regular expression in method to conditionally format record rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to conditionally set a format of names with a "The" at the beginning.  My regular expression works, but I don't know how to make it a conditional statement (basically if this record contains a "the" at the beginning, then "do splitting". As I'm showing a huge table of data,  I'd like to keep this efficient.

```
Class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  def adjusted_name

    if "name LIKE ?", 'The%'
      set_name = self.name.split('The ')[1]
      self.name = format('%s, The', set_name)
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Is your intention to modify the data in the database with the new format, or only to change the way it's displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[gsub](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/String/gsub) with a regex should do the trick:

```
def adjusted_name
    self.name = name.gsub(/^The (.*)$/, '\1, The')
end
```